# Starting with window application for retriving list of software and hardware installed on remote pc

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, wmi

I want to create an application that can give me a description of all the softwares and hardware installed on a computer that is connected through a Local Network.

In Hardware Description - I want something like the list shown in **Device manager** and in software description i want a list of all the softwares installed in remote pc as shown in **"add and remove programs".**

How should i start for this. What i need to implement. I havent used any API before so plz be little descriptive so that i can implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) (Windows Management Instrumentation), I know you asked for the answer to be 'descriptive' but your question opens a pretty big topic and there probably isn't a quick 1,2,3 type answer for it.