# Retrive List of hardware and software installed on remote machine in LAN. Which DLL to Use?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, networking, wmi

I am trying to retrieve a list of all hardware like

> Device Manager

and Softwares installed like in

> "Add and Remove Programs"

on a remote system in LAN. Is it their any 1 or 2 dlls to include instead of all dll for each hardware. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is reasonably vague, but I think what you want to use is [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) (Windows Managment Instrumentation)

Basically, it seems to be the same question as [Starting with window application for retriving list of software and hardware installed on remote pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161721/starting-with-window-application-for-retriving-list-of-software-and-hardware-inst/2161753#2161753).

Comment: I believe that Device Manager actually uses WMI to get the data (not 100% sure though). Anyway, most if not all information displayed in Device Manager can be obtained fro direct or indirect of CIM_LogicalDevice.